# What are the rules?

Tags: harry-potter-rah

I got the game, "Harry Potter: Rescue at Hogwarts" used, but there are no instructions. I've done a solid Internet search but had no luck. The Mattel site shows the game, but it has no instructions available for download. I don't even necessarily need the actual instructions, I just want to know how to play!

Does anyone have this one? It's Mattel C5555. Thanks.

Comment: it is not an answer, however I have had luck twice finding someone who had the game over at board game geeks and asking them if they would photo copy the instructions. I had to do this for Super Giant Monster Showdown. I sent the guy $10 because I really wanted the rules and he sent me a very high quality photo copy.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I've posted one there. We'll see if there's any response.

Comment: From the entry for the game I did not see anyone who had a copy. You may not be able to find them. Another option is to find a game shop that is selling it and see if they would make the same photo copy deal. Best of luck.

Comment: It may also be worth contacting Mattel directly. The website has an email or chat form. Since they have so many of their instructions online (including a load of other Harry Potter games), it may be possible for them to post this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mattel came through by posting the instructions on their web site!

http://service.mattel.com/us/product_detail.asp?SearchString=c5555&displayOption=&brandName=&id=c5555